# Selenium reusing browser session

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I would like to have a single long-running browser session, that is reused between separate runs of my script. Thus allowing me to avoid logging in every time my script runs. Using other answers I have a working solution:

```
session_info = load_from_json()

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()

driver = webdriver.Remote(
            command_executor=session_info["executor_url"], 
            desired_capabilities={},
            options = options)
driver.session_id = session_info["session_id"]
```

This has an unwanted side effect of leaving an orphaned chrome-webdriver session laying around on top of the already existing browser session. I was wondering what I can do to avoid having an extra orphaned session.

Answer (score 0):

Prior to loading a new session try to clear both session and local storage.

```
driver.getSessionStorage().clear();
driver.getLocalStorage().clear();
```

Comment: putting this code before `driver.session_id = session_info["session_id"]` results in a `AttributeError: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'getSessionStorage'`